# Python while loop maybe need a break statement?

Tags: python

I need for this code to stop calculating the increase of the salary after year 20. I tried adding another while loop but that caused an infinite loop to occur. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
RATE = 2.0
INITIAL_SALARY = 37238.00
salary = INITIAL_SALARY
year = 1

print("Murdock County")
print("Teacher Salary Schedule")
print()
print("Year          Salary")
print("----          ------")



while year < 31 :
    print("%4d  %15.2f"  % (year, salary))
    increase = salary * RATE / 100
    salary = salary + increase
    year = year + 1
```

Comment: How about using an if inside the loop?

Comment: Is that a typo? `while year < 31` instead of `while year < 21` ? That would, if I understand correctly, solve your problem..

Comment: Do you mean stop the  calculation at year 21 but print the unchanging salary for years 21 to 31 ?  If so an if inside the while loop should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I still need it to print years 21 to 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably typed 31 instead of 21, so

```
while year < 21 :
    # your code
```

Or you could probably mean that after 21 the salary is no longer increased, so:

```
while year < 31 :
    print("%4d  %15.2f"  % (year, salary))
    if year < 21:
       increase = salary * RATE / 100
       salary += increase
    year += 1
```

You can use a for loop alternatively because you know the number of times the loop will be executed, and make some improvements as probably removing the variable INITIAL_SALARY, using a string enclosed in tripe double or single quotation marks to avoid using too many print statements:

```
RATE = 2.0
salary = 37238.00

print("""Murdock County
Teacher Salary Schedule

Year          Salary
----          ------""")


for year in range(1, 31):
    print("%4d  %15.2f" % (year, salary))
    if year < 21:
        increase = salary * RATE / 100
        salary += increase
    year += 1
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, I still need it to print the unchanged salary years from 21 to 30.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf ,  yes, thanks!  I had tried an if statement but had it in the wrong place.  I'm just learning Python, so I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: @AndrewN., it has been a pleasure to help you, I hope you consider some of the suggestions I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
while year < 31 :
    print("%4d  %15.2f"  % (year, salary))
    if year < 21:
       increase = salary * RATE / 100
       salary = salary + increase
    year = year + 1
```

Comment: Will this continue to print the unchanging salary for years 21 to 30?

Comment: Yes. As the scope of `salary` variable is outside the `while` loop

Comment: Outstanding! I had tried an 'if' statement earlier, just had it in the wrong place.... I'm still learning lol